How to prove triangle is equilateral without triangle congruence or similarity theorems?
I'm examining the following basic theorem:

An isosceles triangle with vertex angle equal to $60^\circ$ has other two angles equal.

(I know this is true for base angle as well, but I'm interested exactly in that part)
So, given $_\Delta ABC$ is isosceles with $AB=BC$, and $\angle ABC = 60^\circ$, I want to prove that $\angle ABC = \angle CAB = \angle ACB = 60^\circ$.
The limitations are to use elementary geometry only (no trigonometry or coordinate method), not to use triangle similarity or congruence theorems, not using circles, not using the properties of isosceles triangle (its base angles being equal). Ideally, I want a proof that mainly uses properties of supplementary angles, vertical angles, as well as properties of two lines and a transversal. For example, it is okay to use the sum of angles in a triangle or an external angle theorem, as they are independent from the facts above.
Of course, I'm familiar with the widely-known proof. I am looking for the abovementioned alternative.
This proof will let me use this theorem as a basic building block for other proofs of basic theorems, in order to make their truthness independent from triangle congruency or similarity.
My idea:

Through point $C$ construct a line parallel to $AB$.
Parallelism implies Equal Alternate Angles, thus the angle we denote as $\alpha$, which is alternate interior to the given angle $ABC$ is equal to $60^\circ$.
Two Straight Lines make Equal Opposite Angles, so the angle opposite to $\alpha$ is also equal to $60^\circ$.
Bisectors of Adjacent Angles between Straight Lines Meeting at Point are Perpendicular, so we can drop a perpendicular from point $C$, and calculate the remaining angles at this vertex.

Is it solid enough?


So I doubt it will be possible without that. Usually the SAS test is assumed, as it appeals the most to intuition: Draw a length, construct some angle, and cut an arc of another length on it.

Use $A+B+C=180$ degrees. and the condition two angles are equal.

@Piquito they can't use the condition that the two angles are equal. "not using the properties of isosceles triangles"

@DS I have a basic idea which I will add to the question.

I think my first comment was true. You have to take one of the congruency tests as a postulate.

@DS So the actual problem here is that the construction itself requires a congruency test? But why if it only involves straightedge and compass?

I'm not much of an expert on the foundations of euclidean geometry, and the rigor required for the definitions, but I think a straightedge-compass construction can't rigorously prove the $SAS$ test

The construction does not require the congruency test. Your last paragraph in the question isn't clear. Can you explain?

iirc Hilbert made SAS an axiom, and Euclid considered the construction-type proof rigorous enough

From a reddit thread : "There's a lot of hidden assumptions underlying some of the "obvious" reasoning in Euclid."

@DS Post had been edited.

Hmm, looks like somewhere along the line, you've inherently assumed that the parallel line bisects the exterior angle at $C$ (the 120 angle divided into 2 $60^\circ$ angles)

Another point of suspicion is that your proof does not use the fact that $AB=BC$

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
